# group by and sort by biggest groups

Tags: mysql, group-by

Suppose I have a blog where users can make a comment. If the comment is spam, people can vote it deleted.
When that happens, a row is inserted in this table:

```
SPAM_REPORTS
comment_id - ip
```

The table is unique on `comment_id, ip`.

Now I want to get outputted the comment_id's ordered by those with the maximum number of reports.

Suppose `SPAM_REPORTS` is:

```
comment_id         ip
     6      888.xxx.xxx.xxx
     5      111.xxx.xxx.xxx
     5      222.xxx.xxx.xxx
     6      444.xxx.xxx.xxx
     1      333.xxx.xxx.xxx
     5      555.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I want the output to be:

```
comment_id  count
    5        3
    6        2
    1        1
```

Comment: I think you should `group by and sort by the biggest groups`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 select comment_id , count(*) as count from SPAM_REPORTS
 group by comment_id 
 order by count desc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd07b1/3)